# Springboot endpoint fails when the war is deploy in an external Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I am working with springboot 1.5.9 and the extarnal version of the Tomcat is 8.5.7. First I generate the initial package with `Spring Initializr` without choose any option. After I create a class controller and write a method with a endpoint (Get method) which returns a String.

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String index() {

       return "REST API HERE ";
    }

}
```

If I run the api with the embedded tomcat and make a call with postman all works fine.

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2018-01-25 20:50:29.954  INFO 5944 --- [           main] com.test.TestApplication                 : Starting TestApplication on Alvaro with PID 5944 (C:\Projects\dev\test\target\classes started by Alvaro in C:\Projects\dev\test)
2018-01-25 20:50:29.956  INFO 5944 --- [           main] com.test.TestApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-25 20:50:29.982  INFO 5944 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3439f68d: startup date [Thu Jan 25 20:50:29 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-25 20:50:30.697  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-25 20:50:30.709  INFO 5944 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
018-01-25 20:50:30.710  INFO 5944 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-01-25 20:50:30.768  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-25 20:50:30.768  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 787 ms
2018-01-25 20:50:30.865  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-25 20:50:30.868  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 20:50:30.869  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 20:50:30.869  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 20:50:30.869  INFO 5944 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 20:50:31.040  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3439f68d: startup date [Thu Jan 25 20:50:29 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-25 20:50:31.077  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.TestController.index()
2018-01-25 20:50:31.079  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object         org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-25 20:50:31.079  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-25 20:50:31.096  INFO 5944 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 20:50:31.096  INFO 5944 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 20:50:31.116  INFO 5944 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 20:50:31.191  INFO 5944 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-25 20:50:31.234  INFO 5944 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-01-25 20:50:31.236  INFO 5944 --- [           main] com.test.TestApplication                 : Started TestApplication in 1.434 seconds (JVM running for 1.633)
2018-01-25 20:54:31.002  INFO 5944 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-01-25 20:54:31.002  INFO 5944 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-01-25 20:54:31.011  INFO 5944 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 9 ms
```

[Test with postman with enbedded tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8qdN.png)

After that I generate the war (using package) and put into a external tomcat. When the tomcat deploy the war there is not errors.

```
2018-01-25 21:14:29.713  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.test.ServletInitializer              : Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Alvaro with PID 8508 (C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes started by Alvaro in C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\bin)
2018-01-25 21:14:29.714  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.test.ServletInitializer              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-25 21:14:29.754  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@562627a1: startup date [Thu Jan 25 21:14:29 CET     2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-25 21:14:30.390  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 636 ms
2018-01-25 21:14:30.708  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-25 21:14:30.710  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 21:14:30.710  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 21:14:30.710  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 21:14:30.710  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 21:14:30.710  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-25 21:14:31.002  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@562627a1: startup date [Thu Jan 25 21:14:29 CET     2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-25 21:14:31.068  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String com.test.TestController.index()
2018-01-25 21:14:31.071  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-25 21:14:31.072  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-25 21:14:31.094  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 21:14:31.094  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 21:14:31.125  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-25 21:14:31.219  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-25 21:14:31.232  INFO 8508 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.test.ServletInitializer              : Started ServletInitializer in 1.854 seconds (JVM running for 3.885)
2018-2018 21:14:31.249 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [3.429] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.250 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\docs] de la aplicaci¾n web
2018-2018 21:14:31.262 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\docs] has finished in [12] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.262 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\examples] de la aplicaci¾n web
2018-2018 21:14:31.400 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\examples] has finished in [138] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.401 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\host-manager] de la aplicaci¾n web
2018-2018 21:14:31.414 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [14] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.414 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\manager] de la aplicaci¾n web
2018-2018 21:14:31.426 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\manager] has finished in [12] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.426 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Despliegue del directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\ROOT] de la aplicaci¾n web
2018-2018 21:14:31.437 INFORMACIËN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.27\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [11] ms
2018-2018 21:14:31.440 INFORMACIËN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018-2018 21:14:31.447 INFORMACIËN [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
2018-2018 21:14:31.449 INFORMACIËN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3656 ms
```

But when I do the same text with postman, i receive a 404 error:

[Postman error with the war deploy in an external Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLQs3.png)

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0    </modelVersion>

    <groupId>com    </groupId>
    <artifactId>test    </artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT    </version>
    <packaging>war    </packaging>

    <name>test    </name>
    <description>test    </description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot    </groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent    </artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE    </version>
        <relativePath/>     <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8    </project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8    </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8    </java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot    </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web    </artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot    </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat    </artifactId>
            <scope>provided    </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot    </groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test    </artifactId>
            <scope>test    </scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot    </groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin    </artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I'm lost because I don't know if the problem is with the external tomcat configuration, or with the springboot package.

I checked a lot of things:

1. I follow all the steps to deploy an external war with springboot (in fact, the war deploy without errors) Like this doc indicate: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html
2. I checked if the the port 8080 in the external tomcat was open.
3. I tested in diferents tomcats (one in windows and two in linux).
4. I checked the java version.

But nothing seems to work.

If you need more info please ask me. Thank you for your help!

I added the follow web.xml in test/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml. But the problem continue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation    </param-name>
        <param-value>test.Application    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener    </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricsFilter    </filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy    </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricsFilter    </filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*    </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet    </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet    </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute    </param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT    </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1    </load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet    </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/    </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did u added the web.xml?

Comment: I am using tomcat 8. And the servlet version is 3+. Need I add web.xml?? The official doc indicate that web.xml is only for old containers.

Comment: I suggest to give it a try. Spring Boot is not standard Java approach, and I don't know the exact nature of your project. IF you add a proper web.xml and it start to works that should be a good starting point.

Comment: @Black.Jack I added the web.xml, but the problem persists. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could u upload the file somewhere too?

Comment: @Black.Jack I upload the change in the description. You can see it there. Thx!

Comment: It seems a bad web.xml...

Comment: @Black.Jack Where is the mistake? I use the web.xml describe here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html Thx!

Comment: To which context is your app deployed? By default, Tomcat will use the name of your WAR, which seems to be `test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Try accessing http://localhost:8080/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test instead

Comment: BTW, you don't need web.xml with Servlet 3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Tomcat will use the name of the WAR as the context to which your app will be deployed. In your case, the context name will be `test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` so the URL to access your app will be http://localhost:8080/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/.

If you want your app to be deployed at the root, you may name your file `ROOT.war`. You can also specify a different context name in a `context.xml` file (included or external to your war).

[See Tomcat doc about context here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)

Comment: It was that. Thank you!